# PHP/MySQL not updating database or reloading page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a php to change a users password but my php keeps getting hung up on something.  I have my code successfully check to ensure you entered the old password correctly, which works fine, however now when I try to update the password with the new password the page changes to a blank screen.

```
<?php

require("common.php");

if(empty($_SESSION['email']))
{
    header("Location: main.php");

    die("Redirecting to Frontpage");
}

$fname = $_SESSION['fname']['fname'];
$lname = $_SESSION['lname']['lname'];
$email = $_SESSION['email']['email'];


$queryPost = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE email = :email";

$stmt = $db->prepare($queryPost);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();

$pass_correct = false;

if($row)
    {
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['oldpass'] . $row['salt']);
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
        {
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
        }

        if($check_password === $row['pass'])
        {
    $pass_correct = true;
        }
    else
    {
    header("refresh:2; url=accountsettings.php");
    die("Old Password incorrect....turning around");
    }
    }

if($pass_correct)
    {
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));

        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['newpass'] . $salt);

        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
        {
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
        }

        $query = "UPDATE db SET pass=':pass', salt=':salt' WHERE email = :email";

        $query_params = array(':pass' => $password, ':salt' => $salt);

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

        header("refresh:2; url=accountsettings.php");
            die("Password changed....turning around");
    }



?>
```

I feel its getting caught up at the if($pass_correct) statement

Comment: Remove the quotes in `pass=':pass', salt=':salt'`

Comment: I tried that first thing and I get the same result...blank page loads.  It doesn't change the password or redirect back.  I feel like I'm missing something so easy

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? Is you error reporting enabled to check the possible errors in the page?

Comment: Javad you mad genius!  I was missing a token in my query_params according to the error_logs.